# Removing 'Add new...' from object menu on a specific view

Tags: plone, archetypes, zope3

What would be the easiest way (using code in a view) to remove the 'Add new...' menu item from the object menu for a specific view?

I've used IConstrainTypes before, but it seems a little strange since it stores the constrains between requests.

Comment: I was really hoping that I can prevent it from being rendered in the first place. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it very easily with a Diazo rule like that:

```
<drop css:content="#plone-contentmenu-factories" css:if-content=".template-your_view" />
```

Comment: Does this basically also amount to hiding it with CSS?

Comment: Yes, but server side.